# Rmarkdown: cross-reference image included with markdown syntax

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference

I would like to cross-reference an image which I include with the markdown `![caption with spaces](path/to/image.png)` syntax.

I would like to be able to cross-reference this image as `\@ref(fig:caption-with-spaces)`.

I am using `bookdown::pdf_document2`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you mean to use round parentheses, or is the use of curly braces intended? Please double-check.

Comment: I did mean to include curly brackets, as that is the syntax :)

Comment: Apologies, just checked my file -  did make a mistake, i meant parentheses, but my question remains :) I'll update the question. Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R Markdown adds a figure ID when generating figures via R, but not for pure Markdown images. In this case, you can add an ID yourself:

```
![Caption with spaces](path/to/pictures.png){#fig:caption-with-spaces}
```

The id can be chosen freely, but should start with `fig:`.

---

If you'd like a keep everything in pure Markdown, but don't want to add identifiers manually, you can use a [pandoc Lua filter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html):

```lua
local stringify = (require 'pandoc.utils').stringify
function Image (img)
  if img.identifier == '' then
    img.identifier = 'fig:' .. stringify(img.caption):gsub('%s', '-'):lower()
    return img
  end
end
```

Use by adding a `pandoc_args` parameter to your output settings:

```yaml
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    pandoc_args: ['--lua-filter', 'auto-image-ids.lua']
```

Comment: Ah, nice solution. I didn't realise that this was possible

Comment: Thanks @jwalton. I didn't get to upvote your answer yet, would you undelete? The knitr solution is a nice alternative and it would be a loss omit it here.

Comment: Thanks guys, to confirm, after adding this figure id, I can then cross-reference it using \@ref(fig:caption-with-spaces)?

Answer (score 10):

Labels can be attached to images included in markdown using the syntax `![caption](path/to/image){#fig:anchor_name}`.

That said, there are two further options

1. Use LaTeX's `\includegraphics` command.
2. Use knitr's `include_graphics` function.

A LaTeX solution would look something like:

```
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{path/to/picture.png}
   \caption{Caption with spaces}
   \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

A knitr solution would look like

````
```{r, fig.cap = "Caption with spaces", label="example"}
knitr::include_graphics("path/to/picture.png")
```
````

With both of these solutions you can cross-reference the resulting image with `\ref{fig:example}`.

Comment: It's important to realise that the `fig.cap` is essential for the label to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image with R as:

```
{r schematic, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Diseño de circuito esquemático", fig.align="center"}
knitr::include_graphics("schematic.png")
```

Then to reference the image:
`\ref{fig:schematic}`

Note: I tried other ways to reference the image like `\@ref(fig:schematic)` but this did not work for me